# I receive false result comparing indices of two letters

Tags: javascript

I wrote a method that takes a string in and returns true if the letter "z" appears within three letters **after** an "a". You may assume that the string contains only lowercase letters.

```
function nearBy_az(string) {
    var i
    var j
    len = string.length
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
            if (string[i] === "a" && string[j] === "z" && j - i <= 3) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like a nested loop is a wrong approach to that solution. And do yourself a favor and use semicolons.

Comment: *"Write a method..."*: hold on now. You had a question, or an order?

Comment: You've included what you tried (which is good!) but not what went wrong or how, or even test data to reproduce the problem with.

Comment: You could try using Regex instead.

Comment: Why cant you use a regex to match the string?

Comment: @epascarello how is using semi-colons beneficial?

Answer (score 0):

You just simply use a regex, if you are fine using a regex.
Here is what you could do.

```js
var strCondition = new RegExp(/(.*?|^)a[a-z]{0,2}z/);

var string = "az";
console.log(strCondition.test(string));
string = "adz";
console.log(strCondition.test(string));
string = "abcz";
console.log(strCondition.test(string));
string = "abcdz";
console.log(strCondition.test(string));
string = "abcdez";
console.log(strCondition.test(string));
```

```js
//var inputString = "abz";

function verifyString(inputString) {
  var exist = false;

  debugger;
  for (var idx = 0; idx < inputString.length; idx++) {
    if (inputString.charAt(idx) === 'a') {
      var subStr = inputString.substr(idx, 4);
      if (subStr.indexOf('z') !== -1) {
        exist = true;
      }
    }
  }
  return exist;
}

var inputString = "az";
console.log(verifyString(inputString));
inputString = "adz";
console.log(verifyString(inputString));
inputString = "abcz";
console.log(verifyString(inputString));
inputString = "abcdz";
console.log(verifyString(inputString));
inputString = "abcdez";
console.log(verifyString(inputString));
```

Comment: Thanks Sreekanth! Almost everything understandable except  if (substr.indexOf('z') !== -1) {return true} Not equal to the last character? If it is not equal to the last char? Sorry I am new in coding, recently started.

Comment: Thank you for a RegExp method, I used it once, precisely saw someone use it with anti vowel method.  But here (.*?|^) these symbols are hard to predict. I mean I read on MDN javascript how to use RegExp but there is no description of what you used here. Can you please explain a bit how did you chose these characters? Thank you!

Comment: basically it .*? means to match any character before 'a' and ^ means where 'a' is the first character. Technically, (.*? | ^)a means match 'a' if it exists in the middle or match 'a' where it is at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to remember it!